# ArcGIS lookup (Spatial Analyst) returns ERROR 000861 raster not valid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have the [HWSD](http://www.fao.org/soils-portal/soil-survey/soil-maps-and-databases/harmonized-world-soil-database-v12/en/) loaded. I want to export multiple attributes so that they are stored as raster values. This can be done with the Lookup tool from Esri. Running this tool gives the following errors:

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Google the error (no helpful answers)
- Check path names for whitespaces (no change in error)
- Convert the input raster from .bil to .tif (no change in error)
- Check if all extensions are enabled

Backgroundinfo:

- ArcGIS 10.6
- Win 10 pro 64 bit (version 10.0.16299 build 16299)

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look into the error there is a period (.) in the field name which is invalid. Also the field name length should follow the rules of the format you are using. If the output is Esri Grid, the maximum field name length is 10 characters.

You can refer to [Error code: 000861](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00851-00875-000861.htm) and [Error code: 010085](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/010001-020000/tool-errors-and-warnings-10076-10100-010085.htm) for more information.

Comment: That indeed was the problem. The table was based on a temporary join. Saving the join to write it to the disk and remove the (.) solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it worked. :)